# YII2 application working on local but PAGE NOT FOUND error on live

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a simple application in YII2 and it is working fine at my local machine but giving me Not Found (#404) "Page Not Found" error on live server.
Local URL: http://localhost:8080/basicapp/web/index.php?r=adminPanel%2Fstatemaster%2Findex

Live URL: http://XXXX.com/web/index.php?r=adminPanel%2Fstatemaster%2Findex

I am not using pretty URL, and didn't change in web.php.  just added module info in the file. Code Snippet:

```
'modules' => [
    'adminpanel' => [
        'class' => 'app\admin\adminpanel',
    ],
    'studentPanel' => [
        'class' => 'app\Student\dashboard',
    ],
],
```

I can provide detial, whatever is required.

Comment: Well, you are missing /basicapp/ from your live URL. http://XXXX.com/basicapp/web/index.php?r=adminPanel%2Fstatemaster%2Findex

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your prompt reply. Actually basicapp is name of the folder at my local, now the application is on live server.

Comment: Is your web server configured the same way as your live server?

Comment: Would you please elaborate little more, I developed this application on my local machine and I am able to access using mentioned URL but after going online it giving error.

Comment: What is the root for your www folder in local and what is it in live? and what do you mean with "basicapp" is name of the folder at my local?

Comment: At local: C:\xampp\htdocs\basicapp, online: public_html, basicapp is a folder on my local machine where application files are saved.

Comment: but live? what is the folder structure of your live web server? is it Yii /www/html/Yiifolders or something else? have you tryed just accessing xxxxx.com and see what happens?

Comment: Online server file path is: /home/xxxxxcpanel/public_html/, I am using godaddy server.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone have similar problem, Just change your naming of models and controllers.
In my problem, model and controller names were like StateMasterController etc but it should be StatemasterController, mind the M.
It works for me, may be this can help you.

Thanks